# Strange behavior of showingDeleteConfirmation on UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

A `UITableViewCell` has a `showingDeleteConfirmation` flag that you can read. As the name suggests, this allows you to know if the cell is showing the 'delete' button. There are two ways this delete button can be displayed:

1. Swiping across a row.
2. Entering edit mode for the cell and then pressing the '-' icon on the left of the row.

I set up some logging to check the value of this flag in the cell's `willTransitionToState:`. And I found something that confuses me.

In example (1), `showingDeleteConfirmation` is `YES` both when swiping across the row and when exiting editing for the cell (by touching outside the row after the swipe).

In example (2), `showingDeleteConfirmation` is `NO` when touching the '-' icon, but `YES` when exiting editing for the cell (again by touching outside the row).

First, can someone confirm this is the case, and that it is not a quirk of my `UITableViewCell` subclass.

Why would this be inconsistent? In my opinion behavior (2) is better, since it describes what is on screen at the time `willTransitionToState:` is called.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried checking your logic in `didTransitionToState:` instead?  It seems to make sense that at the instance you tap the minus button it would be `NO` and that later once the animation has finished it would change to `YES`.